# How to redirect users if not my ip?

Tags: .htaccess

OK, I have boonex script installed and the original .htaccess is on http://codeshare.io/zSQvq.
I want to redirect everyone to another directory on the server (whilst I build the site)
The only allowed will be my 2 IPs. And for that I added:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(18\.13\.112\.222|18\.4\.144\.106)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/inamoment/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:// mysite .com/inamoment/$1 [R=302,L]
```

after RewriteEngine on

and when I do that I receive a 500 Internal Server Error.

Is there maybe something contradictory?
Do you mind to have a look on http://codeshare.io/zSQvq

Many thanks
(http:// mysite .com/ was separated on purpose)

Comment: Can you check your error.log and see why 500 is coming?

Comment: Do you have those spaces in the url in your htaccess file like you do in your question?

Comment: * the spaces are on purpose))

Comment: OK, it seems that accepted now but only with one IP. is it wrong written?

Comment: [If you have solved your problem by yourself, then kindly use the `Post Your Answer` button to answer your own question and mark it as the accepted answer. Do not change the title to `SOLVED` that's not how this website works.](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And everything works with:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(192\.249\.19\.122|81\.13\.18\.56)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/inamoment/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site(dot)com/inamoment/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Where on the first line: I tell that if the visit is not from any of those IPs;
2nd and 3rd line:  says to redirect to site.com/inamoment

All the best